# A combinatoric problem about a nine-node complete graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Last update is on 2024/3/7 22:13:a crucial error fixed.

---

At first, I feel sorry for my poor English.As it said in my title,my problem is that how to prove that:

> In a complete graph with 9 points, where the edges are colored black and white, there must be either a completely 3-node white cycle or a completely 4-node black clique.

**Please note**,"black" & "white" mentioned in my words are specifically earmarked ,what my problem meant is not

> "In a complete graph with 9 points, the edge color is black and white, there must either be an 3-node all-white cycle or an 4-node all-black clique, or there must be an 3-node all-black cycle or an 4-node all-white clique."

What's more,if you help me prove that when 9 turns to 8,the statement becomes false,and give me an example of graph for it,I'd be rather grateful.Thanks a lot for your listening.

Comment: Hi welcome to MSE! First, please provide any work you have currently completed on the problem, and what the problem is for (people will be more likely to help this way). Second, If the edges are specifically earmarked, how are they specifically earmarked? Or by earmarked do you just mean we need to use white to show the cycle and black to show the clique?

Comment: Is something missing from the problem? Like, an all black clique of a certain size? Because if there's a single black edge, its endpoints will be a black clique of size $2$. Otherwise the whole graph is white with lots of completely white cycles.

Comment: @user469053,I forgot to write the node limitation for the number of nodes.I'm so sorry for it.

Comment: The alleged duplicates don't answer the main question here. They provide an example as requested at the end of the present question, and so prove $R(4,3)\geq9$. But in the present posting, the main question concerns $R(4,3)\leq9$. One of the duplicates' answers doesn't address this at all, while the other has an incorrect proof. Here Qise's answer gives a correct proof.  Since it strikes me as strange to close the question that has the right answer while leaving open the questions with no/wrong answers to the present question, I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @AndreasBlass My apologies, I was in a hurry and did not notice that the proof there was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be the subgraph induced by white edges and $B$ = $G\backslash W$.
If there's a vertex $v$ with $\delta_W(v)\ge4$: call $a,b,c,d$ four of its neighbors. If either couple among $\{a,b,c,d\}$ is a white edge we have a white triangle. If not, $\{a,b,c,d\}$ is a black $K_4$.

Suppose now that all vertices in $G$ have $\delta_W(v)\le 3$. Because the number of odd degree vertices is even, there's necessarily a vertex $v$ st $\delta_W(v)\le2$, or in other words, $\delta_B(v) \ge 6$. Take its 6 neighbors along black edges: $a,b,c,d,e,f$. Let $G'$ be the graph induced by these six vertices. By [Friends and stranger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers), there's either a white or a black triangle among these, which concludes the proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot!Your reply fits my thought so well~